# Debugging or running single test disabled as soon as providing local jest mock

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to debug my unit tests or run them one at a time but for some reason can't. What I figured out is jest seems to be behaving abnormally or is not able to process arrow functions normally. Both way of mocking are same and test pass but the uncommented approach disables the debug mode for some reason

```
// index.js
const dependency = require("./dependency");

const ModuleUnderTest = () => {
  const data = dependency()();
  return data;
};

module.exports = ModuleUnderTest;
```

```
// dependency.js
module.exports = () => () => "some data";
```

```
// index.test.js
const index = require("./index");
const { getData } = require("./dependency");

// This doesn't let you debug the test
jest.mock("./dependency.js", () => () => () => "some other data");
// This lets you debug
// jest.mock("./dependency.js", () => {
//   return () => () => "some other data";
// });

describe("test suite", () => {
  test("test1", () => {
    expect(index()).toBe("some other data");
  });
});
```

In case you would like to repro locally, here is the repo which reproduces the steps: https://github.com/cravi24/test-js/blob/master/index.test.js
For VS code, jest runner has a plugin which enables you to run jest test with left-clicks or one ui button like option. Both fail for debugging

Comment: *But why test pass with mock working as expected when i run all the tests in the test file.* - I'm not sure what's the meaning of this. What are the expectations? In the code you posted, `ModuleUnderTest` was mocked to be `undefined`. Can you show tests that weren't shown? They seem to be relevant.

Comment: Test set doesn't seem to be relevant here. I have only one test in the test suite. Problem I am facing is that debugging/running single test is possible if I avoid providing mock implementation `jest.mock('./local-dependency-module', () => {});` or by `LocalDependencyModule.mockImplementation(()=> {})`

Comment: I'm still not sure what is the problem, considering that you know that the mock is incorrect. Did you try to provide correct implementation instead of `=> {}`?

Comment: suppose you want to debug test 1, I am unable to do so without removing the mock implementation part. Reason I believe my mock implementation is correct is that if I run the test suite, test runs fine. Not being able to debug is the troubling part. Its confusing the jest plugin somehow and it doesn't allow you to run that single test in either debug or normal run mode

Comment: Please, be more specific regarding debugging, how exactly do you debug a single test in IDEs? Is `jest.mock('./local-dependency-module', () => {})` your real mock? Currently it looks like `ModuleUnderTest.someFunc()` shouldn't work no matter how the test runs because the mock results in `ModuleUnderTest === undefined`. There's not enough information to understand what happens on your end.

Comment: updated the root cause. while trying to create a repo where i could show you ton repro the issue, i found the issue. please check the update for root cause

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. It's true that a lot of problems become self-evident once you try to provide a way to reproduce them. As for your case, I suppose it was a similar but different issue with arrow brackets because these two mocks you posted are really the same, `() => () => <div id="test-component" />` is short syntax for `() => {
  return () => <div id="test-component" />;
}`.

Comment: after you pointed out, i realized i fixed the issue but i don't really know the root cause. I have shared the code repo as well as updated the code above in case you can figure out the issue